# FTPS for linux on .Net Core

Tags: linux, .net, ftp, ssl

There's currently a bug in SslStream that prevents it being used for ftps on Linux: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33506.

Does anyone know of a cross platform, .Net Core compliant, open source, ftps client, that does not make use of SslStream and hence works on Linux.